# LeveneTest and shapiro test to a list of models

Tags: r, loops, lapply, anova

I have this code

```
{r anova-loop}
# loop 
models <- lapply(varlist,
       function(t) lm(formula = paste0("`", t, "` ~ block+irrigation*genotype"),dt))

#Name the list of models to the column name
names(models) = varlist

## apply anova to each model stored in the list, models

lapply(models, anova)
```

How can I run leveneTest and shapiro to all my models generated from a variable list so I can check the anova assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a moment of enlightenment and worked out the Shapiro test

```
    residuals <- lapply(models, residuals)
lapply(residuals, shapiro.test)
```

But still struggling with the Levene Test